# How do I create a LinQ query with an "IN" statement like SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need a LinQ query that does the same thing as below...but I can't seem to figure it out. (I'm using C#)

```
SELECT * FROM Groups WHERE Id IN(
SELECT DISTINCT [GroupId] FROM [MyTable].[dbo].[Detail])
```

NOT This (as marked a duplicate question)

SELECT * FROM Users WHERE User_Rights IN ("Admin", "User", "Limited")

If they are the same then so be it...I'll of course take that as the answer.

Comment: @jeffmercado I know that question "answers" this one -- but honestly the hightest voted one in there is terrible -- I would use .where and Any

Comment: It's not a duplicate of the question above...because it's not a CSV list of items in the "IN" clause like this SELECT * FROM Users WHERE User_Rights IN ("Admin", "User", "Limited")...it's a list of items in another query.

Comment: @jpolo: `Contains()` directly translates to an `IN` clause, whether it was a static list of values or from a subquery. That's precisely what you asked for.

Comment: @JeffMercado -- contains only works on objects -- we need a custom selector for a property so we need to use any.

Comment: @Hogan: it works on scalar values so yes you naturally need to select, which is exactly what the subquery does as well. There's a difference between translating a query and coming up with an equivalent one. `Any()` produces an `EXISTS` clause which isn't exactly what was asked, but still yields a perfectly valid result. Better to share that in the duplicated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Groups collection was in groups and detail was in detail then

```
 groups.Where(z => detail.Any(x => x.groupid == z.id));
```

This checks each element of groups to see if the id property is the same as any groupid property of the detail collection.

---

It is important to note this might not be the best solution for your use case -- if your groups are very large then I would consider making it into a list and using contains -- that will give you hash performance.  For smaller size groups the cost of making the list will be bigger than the performance gain.

```
 var idlist = details.Select(x => x.groupid).ToList();

 groups.Where(z => idlist.Contains(z.id));
```

Comment: I'm getting results from "groups" and from "detail"
But when I follow the example, 
it's ok, up until I get to the "detail.Any"..."Any" is not available for the "detail" resultset.

Comment: Never mind...I figured out what I was doing wrong.  Testing now.